# searching UITableView detailTextLabel and textLabel

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7, textlabel, detailtextlabel

I am using the same code displayed in this Stackoverflow URL [How do I link the search bar to display results in swift/xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900415/how-do-i-link-the-search-bar-to-display-results-in-swift-xcode)

and I am wondering if there is also a way to search the detailTextLabel seeing as I have included a subtitle in the cells.  The subtitles also do not stay aligned with the textLabels when the filtered search is performed.  I am working in Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're able to do so. Under the filterContentForSearchText function, simply return the boolean on whether the title or subtitle contains the search string using an '||' operator.

For example,

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredObjects = objects.filter { object in

  return object.title.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) || object.subtitle.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)

    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```